# Invert object or mark it as negative with minus sign

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, enums

Is it possible to invert an object or mark it as negative?

This is what I want to achieve:

```
DateTime.Now.Add(-TimeUnits.Week)
```

This should return the current date time minus 7 days.

So I have to detect in the `Add` method if the passed object is negative or not!

I've looked at a `Struct` but my experience with them is too little to tell whether this is even possible or not!
Currently, I'm having an enum and is very limited of course. **I'm not specifically bound to an enum, so it can be any other object!**

My enum `TimeUnits`:

```
public enum TimeUnits
{
    Once = 0,
    Day = 1,
    Week = 2,
    Month = 3,
    Quarter = 4,
    Year = 5
}
```

I have an extension method on `DateTime` where I want to pass an object to a method `Add` like this:

```
private static DateTime? Add(this DateTime current, TimeUnits unitOfTime)
{
    switch (unitOfTime)
    {
        case TimeUnits.Once:
            return null;
        case TimeUnits.Day:
            return current.AddDays(1);
        case TimeUnits.Week:
            return current.AddDays(7);
        case TimeUnits.Month:
            return current.AddMonths(1);
        case TimeUnits.Quarter:
            return current.AddMonths(3);
        case TimeUnits.Year:
            return current.AddYears(1);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("unitOfTime");
    }
}
```

Comment: short answer yes. Enums evaluate out to integers so you can just do negative or multiple by negative 1. Also you would need to change your enum to represent days, ie week = 7, day = 1 (i have no clue how you would handle your month and quarter though.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I thought of as well! The months and quarter are my concerns indeed!

Comment: you should not pluralize enum names if they are not flag enums. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229040.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The enum type is, strictly speaking, nothing but a way of defining named constants for numbers. In other words: the expression `-((int(TimeUnit.Week)` is just another way to write the literal `-2` in a way that is more readable for human beings.

While it is technically perfectly possible to 'negate' such a value (because it really is an int for the compiler), you shouldn't do so. Conceptually, this is a horrible idea, it would be a complete misuse of the concept of enums. - Use simple constants for what you are trying to do or, if possible, define a `Subtract()` method.

Comment: You can even specify an ``enum``'s storage type, e.g. ``enum TimeUnits : long { /* ... */ }``. I highly recommend reading the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/sbbt4032.aspx) about ``enum``'s.

Answer (score 0):

Change your signature to:

```
private static DateTime? Add(this DateTime current, int units, TimeUnits unitOfTime)
```

where `units` is the number of `unitOfTime` to add to `current`.

This makes it possible to write:

```
DateTime.Now.Add(  1, TimeUnits.Week); // add a week
DateTime.Now.Add( 42, TimeUnits.Week); // add multiple weeks
DateTime.Now.Add(- 1, TimeUnits.Week); // subtract a week
DateTime.Now.Add(-42, TimeUnits.Week); // subtract multiple weeks
DateTime.Now.Add(  0, TimeUnits.Week); // return `current`
//etc...
```

---

**Note:** Alternatively you may declare it as `double units`, but beware *floating-point arithmetic precision* and *NaN* values.